# Objective-C | Watch property and get notified about change incl. location of change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing

I'm trying to find out why my UITableView changes the width (bigger than phone-screen). Therefore I tried to use KVO, but `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` isn't delivering me the information about the place where the property got changed.
I also tried to set a breakpoint and follow the call stack, to see the place of change - without success - maybe it's happening in another thread.

Does anybody know how to watch a property and get the location of change?

Comment: Check this great article: http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/

Comment: I've already seen that article - no information how to get the place of property-change.

Comment: How did you set the breakpoint?  If you subclass UITableView and override setFrame: and set a breakpoint there, you should see changes.  If you give us a better description of what you're seeing and the bug you're trying to fix, someone may have better advice.

Comment: Instead of KVO, why not subclass `UITableView` and override `setFrame:`. But a breakpoint in there and see who calls it. @i_am_jorf I see you had the same idea :)

Comment: Try logging a backtrace of your stack with NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]); You'll need to override the setter and call super to implement this.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I already tried to override UITableView (setFrame:) and i received the same information.
BUT: I already fixed the issue, just by debugging and a lot of luck.